# SQL between restriction on string values

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want a sql to work in such a way that if i enter between 's1' to 's3' it should not give me 's10' in the including result because '10' is not between '1' and '3'

My create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE food_name
    (`food_name` varchar(4))
;
```

My insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO food_name
    (`food_name`)
VALUES
    ('s1'),
    ('s2'),
    ('s3'),
    ('s10'),
    ('ssss'),
('Tee'),
('Pee')
;
```

My select statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   food_name
WHERE BINARY food_name between 's1' and 's3';
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images - or, even worse, links to images.

Comment: You didn't mention, What answer you except from it, can you edit you question?

Comment: it's not a image it's link to online sql editor with the schema for the problem

Comment: just open the link,then u'll know

Comment: just remove BINARY from query it works fine.

Comment: @AlokSingh cool, never used it... just learned something new :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

`SELECT * 
FROM   food_name
WHERE BINARY food_name between 's1' and 's3' AND (
  (food_name NOT LIKE 's%') OR 
  (
    concat('',SUBSTR(food_name, 2) * 1) = SUBSTR(food_name, 2) -- is 's' + number
    AND
    SUBSTR(food_name, 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
  )
);`

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c72c18/41/0

UPDATE: on a second thought, this somewhat detects the occurrence of numbers within params. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c72c18/71/2

```
SET @FROM_STR = 's1';
SET @TO_STR = 's3';

SELECT * 
FROM   food_name
JOIN (
  SELECT 
  CASE WHEN concat('',SUBSTR(@FROM_STR, 2) * 1) = SUBSTR(@FROM_STR, 2) THEN
    CAST(SUBSTR(@FROM_STR, 2) AS SIGNED)
  ELSE
    NULL
  END
  AS FROM_NUM,  
  CASE WHEN concat('',SUBSTR(@TO_STR, 2) * 1) = SUBSTR(@TO_STR, 2) THEN
    CAST(SUBSTR(@TO_STR, 2) AS SIGNED)
  ELSE
    NULL
  END
  AS TO_NUM

  FROM DUAL
     ) PARAMS
WHERE BINARY food_name between @FROM_STR and @TO_STR AND (
  (food_name NOT LIKE 's%') OR 
  (
    concat('',SUBSTR(food_name, 2) * 1) = SUBSTR(food_name, 2) -- is 's' + number
    AND
    CAST(SUBSTR(food_name, 2) AS SIGNED) BETWEEN PARAMS.FROM_NUM AND PARAMS.TO_NUM
  )
);
```

Comment: could the occurrence of the integer be made dynamic. for eg: if i didn't knew when would 1 in s1 occur.maybe with a regex ?

Comment: just added a version detecting number values without regex, causeI'm afraid there's no way to reference a regex capture group in mysql (without custom functions, see dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) IMHO this is something that can be better achieved using a programming language. i.e. if s1 is passed as parameter #FROM, then you could pass also a derived parameter #FROM_NUM. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `SUBSTRING` and `CAST`

```
SELECT *
FROM   food_name
WHERE cast(substr(a_food_name, 2, length(a_food_name)) as UNSIGNED) between 1 and 3;
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/600357/11)

I have renamed your attribute, since it is a [bad habit](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#duplicating-names-of-objects-of-different-types) to give the same name to a different objects in the database.

Comment: could the occurrence of the integer be made dynamic. for eg: if i didn't knew when would 1 in s1 occur.maybe with a regex ?

Answer (score 0):

By Davide but shorter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   food_name
WHERE SUBSTR(food_name, 2)  between 1 and 3
```

Comment: could the occurrence of the integer be made dynamic. for eg: if i didn't knew when would 1 in s1 occur.maybe with a regex ?

Comment: Can be done, yes. I can update answer later if you wish.